# React.js - Done a API fetch that renders all items, now I want to be able to route on each item to their "own" page with JSON info

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, routes

I have created an React site that renders all items inside an API Fetch on a page. What I want now is to be able to press each item that renders and be able to get routed to a new component that shows "more" info about that item.

**Below I have the following code that takes in the "input" that you can use to search for all items or for a specific item.**

```
  const AgentSearch = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();

       function capitalizeName(input) {
           return input.replace(/\b(\w)/g, (s) => s.toUpperCase());
       }

       console.log('you hit search', input);
       dispatch({
           type: actionTypes.SET_SEARCH_TERM,
           term: capitalizeName(input),
       });
       //do something with input

       history.push('/findagent');
   };
   return (
       <form className='search'>
           <div class='search__input'>
               <SearchIcon className='search__inputIcon' />
               <input value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
           </div>
```

**Here is the code that renders all items:**

```
       eachName = data.map((item) => {
            return (
                <tr>
                    <td class='text-left'>{item.name}</td>
                    <td class='text-left'>{item.agency}</td>
                </tr>
            );
        });
```

Basically what I would like to do is to "catch" the {item.name} and put that into a new query into the fetch once you press that item on the list that got created.

I tried to create a button that covers the whole  class and then put {item.name} as input, but that does not work, also tried to make a "fake" input window that has the {item-name} stored for each item on list, even though the {item-name} gets onto the input window, once i push the button that its connected to, it says it doesn't have any value.

Does anyone know of any clean idea for this? I'm new to React so this might be really easy, haha.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you getting stuck on? Do you get an error somewhere? Do you not know how to check `{item.name}`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to do `onCLick` on the `td`. See the code below.

```
const eachName = data.map((item) => {
    return (
        <tr>
            <td class='text-left' onClick={() => handleNameClick(item.name)}>{item.name}</td>
            <td class='text-left'>{item.agency}</td>
        </tr>
    );
});
```

You can define the `handleNameClick` function. You'll get the `item.name` as the parameter. See below.

```
const handleNameClick = itemName => {
    //your code to send request for the clicked name
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, such a good an easy answer, I just feel stupid now, haha!